# Summing a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This problem was inspired by a typo on a homework assignment for Calculus 2, which covers integration and series.

Find the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$$

Does anyone have any idea regarding where they'd begin with this problem? Maybe some fancy residue calculus trick?

Comment: Based on [Wolfram|Alpha calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F2%5E%28n%5E2%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity), it seems difficult.

Comment: Since your series is somewhat similar to the series obtained changing $n^2$ by $n!$, which represents a transcendental number (a Liouville number), maybe no closed-form exist for your former sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sums of this form are called [Jacobi $\theta$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,a)$. They are not known to possess a closed form, albeit they may be approximated with the help of the [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). They play a very important part in [number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_theory), and the great mathematical genius [Ramanujan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) made great use of them, even inventing [his own](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form). Hope this helps.